# adding metadata to artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

The problem:
I need to be able to use artifacts/versions that passed specific version CI of 3 different project.
For instance project A version x.y.z passed the pipeline with B version x2.y2.z2 and when building C I need to be able to get the artifact of A and B that passed a specific versions.
Therefore I was thinking of pushing additional metadata to the stored artifact in artifactory and when building C to query the artifactory with the data.
How can I add custom data to artifact stored in artifactory as per the CI pipeline with Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Artifactory's [REST api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties) or the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SettingPropertiesonFiles) to easily set properties on an Artifact or an entire Folder.

You can then query Items/Artifacts based on the properties using [REST](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-PropertySearch)

or [CLI using a spec file](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs)

for more advanced querying capabilities you can use [Artifactory's AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language)

Comment: can you share if there is a way to add properties after the build was published, I'd appreciate in a real example of update properties on artifacts that are already deployed

Comment: Once an artifact is deployed to Artifactory, you can add properties regardless of the build state. in fact, a build in Artifactory is simply a set property on a bunch of files (all files that were a part of the build). You can always use the Artifactory UI (there's a property tab on the repo browser) to view the properties. an example of setting a prop would be: curl -uadmin:password -XPUT "http://<your Artifactory>:<port>/artifactory/api/storage/<your repo>/<your File path>?properties=PropKey1=PropVal1;Key2=Val2"

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven Artifactory Plugin

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin

to specify custom metadata for the deployment.